# NSDateFormatter getting date nil with format 'MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a'

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdateformatter

I have `let time = "Jun 08, 2015 11:27 PM"`, converting it to NSDate using following code

```
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(time)
```

getting `date as nil`, even I tried with custom formatter

```
    //MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a
    //formatter.dateFromString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a")
```

still not working, anything missing?

Comment: what the output u need

Comment: date in which format u want to print

Comment: It's very unusual to use `HH` (which is 24 hour clock) in conjunction with `a` (AM/PM). Usually you'd use `hh` with `a`, or use `HH` without `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let time = "Jun 08, 2015 11:27 PM"

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"

    let date = formatter.dateFromString(time)

    formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

     let newString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)

     NSLog("the newString %@", newString)

      let newDate = formatter.dateFromString(newString)

     NSLog("the date %@", newDate!)
```

**the output is**

**the newString** Jun 8, 2015, 12:27 PM

**the date** 2015-06-08 06:57:00 +0000

[image]

Comment: Why is `newString` an hour out?

Comment: actually my device time is different

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, I was missing - "formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"" thinking I am setting the formatter..

Comment: ya correct you need to first set your dataforamt what u need to convert  and second set date format what the answer u need

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following in Plyground and it works correctly.

```
                            let time = "Jun 08, 2015 11:27 PM"

                            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                            formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
                            let date = formatter.dateFromString(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

please try the below code:

```
func dateformat() 
{
    let time = "Jun 08, 2015 11:27 PM"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC");
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(time)
    println(NSDate.date())
}
```